QGIS: Fillstyles does not print to PDF
I symbolized a layer in QGIS 3.28.15-Firenze using fill styles (e.g. Diagonal X, Dense 6).

The styles are shown in QGIS layout mode.

But as I export them to PDF (without compression and as raster/vector, 400dpi) the fill styles are not rendered.

Is it a common issue using these fill styles or do I have specific export settings?

You might try changing the stroke widths and styles of the fill symbol's lines to be in meters at scale, map units or whatever works best.

Those fill styles tend to be printed way smaller and narrower than previewed. Try recreating the fill style by using two line fillings, one rotated by 45°, the other by 135°.

you are right. When I zoom in at my PDF to 300% the fill styles appear. If there is no other way to use enlarge the fill styles symbology, I will build it as you suggested :) thx
